# Why server returns me the Response Code 403 for a valid file in java?

Tags: java, url, httpsurlconnection

I want to get the `Content Length` of this file by java:

```
https://www.subf2m.co/subtitles/farsi_persian-text/SImp4fRrRnBK6j-u2RiPdXSsHSuGVCDLz4XZQLh05FnYmw92n7DZP6KqbHhwp6gfvrxazMManmskHql6va6XEfasUDxGevFRmkWJLjCzsCK50w1lwNajPoMGPTy9ebCC0&name=Q2FwdGFpbiBNYXJ2ZWwgRmFyc2lQZXJzaWFuIGhlYXJpbmcgaW1wYWlyZWQgc3VidGl0bGUgLSBTdWJmMm0gW3N1YmYybS5jb10uemlw
```

When I insert this url in `Firefox` or `Google Chrome`, it downloads a file. but when i want to see that file's size by `Java HttpsURlConnection`, server returns me `Response Code 403` and `Content Length -1`. why this happens? Thanks

```
try {
  System.out.println("program started -----------------------------------------");
  String str_url = "https://www.subf2m.co/subtitles/farsi_persian-text/SImp4fRrRnBK6j-u2RiPdXSsHSuGVCDLz4XZQLh05FnYmw92n7DZP6KqbHhwp6gfvrxazMManmskHql6va6XEfasUDxGevFRmkWJLjCzsCK50w1lwNajPoMGPTy9ebCC0&name=Q2FwdGFpbiBNYXJ2ZWwgRmFyc2lQZXJzaWFuIGhlYXJpbmcgaW1wYWlyZWQgc3VidGl0bGUgLSBTdWJmMm0gW3N1YmYybS5jb10uemlw";
  URL url = new URL(str_url);
  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  con.setConnectTimeout(150000);
  con.setReadTimeout(150000);
  con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
  con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
  con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
  con.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
  con.connect();

  System.out.println("responseCode:  " + con.getResponseCode());
  System.out.println("contentLength:  " + con.getContentLength());
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("error | " + e.toString());
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**output:**

```
program started -----------------------------------------
responseCode:  403
contentLength:  -1
```

Comment: Well, 403 means "[forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)". So apparently, something about the request you're making means the server is refusing to allow you access to it. If you look at the sub-status code, it may provide more information.

Comment: I just tried accessing this URL, and there appears to be some checking of the browser which happens.  My guess is that maybe there is some SSL or handshake process which needs to happen, and it isn't happening from your Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Java user-agent is blocked by some online services (most notably, Cloudflare). You need to set the `User-Agent` header to something else.

```java
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My-User-Agent");
```

In my experience, it doesn't matter what you set it to, as long as it's not the default one:

```java
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "aaa"); // works perfectly fine
```

**EDIT:** looks like this site uses Cloudflare with DDoS protection active - your code won't run the JavaScript challenge needed to actually get the content of the file.